# Matlab saving Guide input data to use it on calculation

Tags: matlab

I have problem using Guide.

I want users to type data in the edit box of guide.

Then for example I want Matlab to save that value as `Velocity`

and use that value to calculate many other things using it.

What I got stuck was like this

I used assignin function

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  Vel=get(handles.edit1, 'String');
  assignin('base', 'Vel', Vel);
```

Than I ran it on command line.

I entered `8` and it gave me

```
a = 8
```

so I typed   `a+4`

Than I gives me `68` or something.

I want 12 for my answer. What can I do??

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a character/string you need to call [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2num.html) first.